# Remove a value from a list using a variable

Tags: python, variables

Using the following code

```
askNumber1 = int(str(raw_input('What range of numbers do you want? Name the minimum number here.')))
askNumber2 = int(str(raw_input('Name the max number you want here.')))
number3 = askNumber2 + 1
number_list = range(askNumber1, number3)    

number4 = str(int(random.randint(askNumber1, askNumber2)))
number_list.remove(number4)
print number_list
print 'Is this your number: ' + number4 + '?'
```

gives me the error:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Is this any way to remove an integer from `number_list` using a variable defined as a random number between two other variables? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @oleiade `list.remove` does not remove by index, but removes the first item whose value matches the passed argument. It is possible to pass strings to this function, though in this case it wouldn't have helped anyway.

Comment: Woops :-) I guess I answered too quickly!

Answer (score 5):

`number4` is a string, while your list consists of integers, so even if your list is `[0,1,2,3]`, doing `number_list.remove("2")` will result in the error since `2!="2"`

Comment: Ohh, thank you :D I had it as a string for later when it printed the number guessed, I just changed number4 to a string in there

Comment: @user1131281 Glad to hear that. If my answer helped you you might want to accept it

Answer (score 1):

Your number4 is a `string`. You need to pass integer value to `number_list.remove(number4)`. Here index needs to be an `integer`.

```
number4 = str(int(random.randint(1, 4)))
type(number4)
```

Output = `<type 'str'>`

```
String = '1'
Integer = 1
String == Integer
```

Output = `False`

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a simpler way:

```
number4 = number_list.pop(random.randint(askNumber1, askNumber2))
```

`list.pop` removes *and* returns an item from a given list.